# Rails conditional routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my url, I want

`localhost/12345` to be routed to `/client/information/12345`

However, I also want users to be able to call

`/client` to go to `/client/index`

I was not able to do this with

`match ':id' => 'client#information'`

because then the word 'client' would be set as the value of `params[:id]`

How can I create a route that will conditionally route to `/client/information` if the id is number, otherwise go to the `/client/index`

Comment: When you say you want `a` to be routed to `b`, do you mean you want `a` to redirect to `b`, or you want it to perform the controller action that would normally be invoked by `b`? Because you're giving URLs for both examples, which would imply a redirect, but your partial solution implies you want to render that action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add constraints to part of a route, you use the `:constraints` option. For instance:

```
match ':id' => 'client#information', :constraints => { :id => /\d+/ }
```

Check out the [segment constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints) section of the Rails Routing docs. It'll explain more details.